# Unable to call finish() from a static handler

Tags: android

I have a main activity that shecks if a user has logged into the service.  If no user has logged in, it opens a new activity:

```
if (userName == null) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

This activity has fields for username and password and a login button.  The user fills in there information then clicks login.  I do the network all in a new thread:

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    try {                   
            Auth myAuth = new Auth(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean isAuth = false;
    isAuth=myAuth.getAuthToken(tUserName.getText().toString(), tPassword.getText().toString());
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putBoolean("isAuth", isAuth);
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setData(b);
    loginHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
        finally { }         }
    }).start();
```

This posts a message back to a handler:

```
private static Handler loginHandler = new Handler () {
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);         

        if(msg.getData().getBoolean("isAuth")){
            // UNABLE TO CALL FINISH
        }
        else
        {
            CharSequence msg2 = "Login Failed";         
            Toast.makeText(context, msg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

I want to auto close the Login Activity if isAuth is true.

My plan for implemeting a login screen maybe going the wrong way.  Is so just let me know and I will look into another way that you suggest.

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct way to do this but here goes.  I modified the code that is run in the thread to call finish().  It seems to work fine.

Comment: isAuth=myAuth.getAuthToken(tUserName.getText().toString(), tPassword.getText().toString());
     if(isAuth){
      finish();
     }
     else {
      Bundle b = new Bundle();
      b.putBoolean("isAuth", isAuth);
      Message msg = new Message();
      msg.setData(b);
      loginHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);
     }

Answer (score 3):

`finish()` is not a static method, which makes it associated with a specific instance of its class -- making it unable to be used from a static method (which by definition is not associated with an instance of a class). Instead of calling `finish()` you might be able to call `myActivity.finish()` if you can get a reference to your activity into the static method.

Perhaps though, a better solution is to simply call startActivityForResult() on the login activity, and let that activity return without user interaction if no login is necessary.